# Starting values for 4 parameter NLS - Chapman Richards function

Tags: r, parameters, curve-fitting, modeling, nls

*Note - I have read several of the posts on how to find starting values for NLS - however, I have not found one with an equation of this form (i.e. 4 parameters, exponent raised to a power)

I am struggling tremendously to find suitable starting values for the Chapman Richards equation, which is commonly used in forestry to model tree growth.

```
y(t) = α * (1 - β * exp(-k * t)^{1/(1-m)})
```

I typically try to find initial values by plotting a line with set parameters, and then tweaking it to fit the data more closely (Image 1). After this I would use the parameters in the function:

```
initial.test <- chapmanRichards(seq(0:15),42,0.95,0.28, 0.67)
plot(age,topHeight,type="p",xlab="year since planting",ylab="Dom height (m)", xlim = c(0,20), ylim = c(0, 50))
lines(seq(0:15),initial.test,col="red")
```

[image]

```
nls(topHeight ~ chapmanRichards(age,a,b,k,m),start=list(a=42,b=0.95,k=0.28,m=0.67))
```

In this case, the program is able to fit the curve with the starting values provided. The problem, however, is when the data is a bit noisy, and after 2 hours of fiddling with the initial test values, I still can't find good enough starting values (Image 2 shows a few attempts on another dataset.

[image]

Can anyone advise on what a good way would be to find suitable starting values? I have thought of creating a matrix that basically runs a sequence for each of the parameters and looping the nls with those starting values, but not sure how the code would look. Any other advice would be greatly appreciated!

PS - would this be something more suited to Excel - solver?

Comment: Isn't the Chapman-Richards model y(t) = α * (1 - β * exp(-k * t))^{1/(1-m)}?

Comment: The way I have it is straight from the {growthmodels} package in R. 

There are supposedly other versions that one can use, such as the 3-parameter derivative to model growth rate.

Comment: Well, I think you should look in some actual publications and not some random R package. `exp(-k * t)^{1/(1-m)}` is the same as `exp(-k * t * {1/(1-m)})` which can be re-parameterized to `exp(a * t)`, i.e., you have two parameters that cannot be estimated independently.

Comment: Hre is some random blog link that specifically discusses using the Chapman-Richards equation with R to fit forest growth data: https://blogg.slu.se/forest-biometrics/2017/03/11/the-chapman-richards-growth-function/

Comment: @Roland that is true, I have been working through Burkhart and Tome (2012) and the same 3 parameter form is given as in the blog that. It must be 
b0(1-e(b1*t))^b2

Comment: @JamesPhillips Thanks! The blog is really useful. I notice it uses the function in the same format as presented in Burkhart and Tome (2012).

Comment: If I understand correctly, it might be possible to refer in any research or academic papers both to the Burkhart and Tome (2012) reference and the forest-growth-specific technique referenced in the blog post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Roland pointed out in the comments the parameters in the equation shown in the question are not identifiable so assuming the equation is as he showed:

```
y = a * (1 - b * exp(-k * t))^{1/(1-m)}
```

take the log of both sides:

```
log(y) ~ log(a) + (1/(1-m)) * log(1 - b * exp(-k*t))
```

and let log(a) = A, 1/(1-m) = M and b = exp(k*B) giving:

```
log(y) ~ A + M * log(1 - exp(k*(B-t))
```

Since B is an offset and k is a scaling we can estimate them as B = mean(t) and k = 1/sd(t).  Using `algorithm = "plinear"` we can avoid starting values for the linear parameters (A and M) provided we specify the right hand side as a matrix such that A times the first column plus M times the second column would give the predicted value.  Thus we have:

```
st <- list(B = mean(t), k = 1/sd(t))
fm0 <- nls(log(y) ~ cbind(1, log(1 - exp(k*(B - t)))), start = st,
  algorithm = "plinear")
```

and then back transform the coefficients so obtained to get the starting values for running the final `nls`.

Also note that `nls2` in the nls2 package can evaluate the model on a grid or at a random set of points to get starting values.

Comment: This is great! Thanks. I will play around with this a bit and see how it fits our data (lots of species and sites to work through!)

Will post here once I have some useful feedback.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I have been cleaning data for the last couple of months, and I can at least get starting values for a few scenarios now